# Cufon text comes with a delay inside a cloned slide (Easy Slider 1.7)

Tags: jquery, clone, cufon, easyslider

I am using Easy Slider 1.7 and I have turned on its "continuous" option. It clones the first slide so continuity don't break using the `clone()` function. Inside this newly cloned slide the cufon text appears after a delay somehow. You can see exactly what I mean [here](http://rwnz.businesscatalyst.com/). Can anyone tell me how to avoid this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it but it does not solve the problem instead I found the solution from Cufon Googlegroup. I just need to call easy slider like listed below and it works good for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.CSS.ready(function(){ 
$("#slider").easySlider({
auto: true,
continuous: true,
imageControl: true,
numericId:'controls'
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use 'Cufon.now();' in a javascript tag to help with that delay - see this article:

http://www.chris-wallace.com/2009/07/25/fix-flash-of-unstyled-content-with-cufon/